# Overlaying a large image onto a small video like snapchat

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to add full screen overlay image on different size of video,
I used ffmpeg it work fine if overlay and video has same scale ratio (same width and height).
Overlay image squeezed if video height and width size is smaller than overlay image but i want to apply like snap chat video they add black view on top and bottom

Ffmpeg command is

```
String[]{"-y", "-i", filePath, "-i",
            overlayPath,
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-filter_complex",
            "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]", "-map",
            "[v]", "-map", "0:a?", "-ac", "2", output};
```

I want following output link is mention below.

[Snapchat output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pzCnZ4qpzbwfSNdVqyarFreyOwSvOVmQ)

[My editing result output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B3kVXTKCqhkDMdj_sMRBasdNOOPyOW7J)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the width and height of the output video.
by using pad attribute you can add a black area in the video if a video with height is small

```
ffmpeg -i intro-blur.mp4 -i 3.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[backd],[backd][1]overlay" out_intro_blur.mp4
```

you can scale overlay image like "scale=1439x2559" here overlay image can be accessed by "[1]"  if you want to scale overlay image you can use [1]scale=1439x2559[scaled_image] after that you can use [scaled_image]  to overlay on video.

example below

```
ffmpeg -i intro-blur.mp4 -i 3.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[backd],[1]scale=1439x2559[scaled_image],[backd][scaled_image]overlay" out_intro_blur.mp4
```

Comment: how to scale overlay image  
Image size is 1439x2559

Comment: you can scale overlay image like "scale=1439x2559" here overlay image can be accessed by "[1]"  if you want to scale overlay image you can use [1]scale=1439x2559[scaled_image] after that you can use [scaled_image]  to overlay on video

Comment: Hello there I am an android application Developer . Looking fow a freelancer work. i can develop video editing apps using ffmepg, like collage video maker,  Mv Master, Cropper , trimmer, stickers on vide etc so if anyone wants to do let me know